# Java Access a DLL file in finger print attendance reader SDK

Tags: java, dll

I’m trying to build a fingerprint attendance system.  I want to directly query attendance records from finger print attendance device to my java application. To do so I want to deal with the SDK of the FP Attendance device. Manufacture of the device has provided the SDK and the documentation which contains a DLL (Riss.Devices.dll) file that has all the necessary entity classes and utility classes.

I googled whole two days to find a way to interact with this dll (Riss.Devices.dll)  file through java and I found many options like JNI, JNA, SWIG etc. But Each and every option is new to me.
If someone can help me to find most suitable way to do this, is very helpful to me because I don’t have much time to hang on.

[Documentation](http://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/03/01/zd2911-user-guide-en/)

Answer (score 0):

I think JNA is the easiest option. Your code would look something like:

```
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class Foo {
    public interface RissDevices extends Library {
        public int BitCheck(int num, int index);
        public int SetBit(int num, int index);
        // TODO: list the other functions you want
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RissDevices library = (RissDevices) Native.loadLibrary("c:/path/to/Riss.Devices.dll", RissDevices.class);
        System.out.println(library.BitCheck(0, 0));
    }
```

Comment: yes, but as i heard JNA can't instantiate class and invoke methods. so how can i use entity classes with in the DLL ??